# Anonymous class instantiation with definition - overwrite protected method

Tags: java, nested, abstract, protected, anonymous

Lets assume I have class:

```
class A {
    protected int x; // no public getter, setter
}
```

Now I want to extend class A, to overwrite 'x' variable. The answer would be:

```
public class SomeClass {
    someMethod() {
        A extendedClass = new MyExtension(5);
    }

    class MyExtension extends A {
        public MyExtension(int x) {
            super.x = x;
        }
    }
}
```

And my question: is there any possibility to do it without defining nested class separately? I mean something like this

```
    someMethod() {
        A extendedClass = new A() {
            // here do something like super.x = 5;
        }
    }
```

I tried with [Calling newly defined method from anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527523/calling-newly-defined-method-from-anonymous-class) but it won't let me instantiate A class. Also I dont want to use reflection.

I simpy dont want to define nested class just to overwrite one property. Origin of the problem is Spring-integration ImapMailReceiver, where I want to overwrite task scheduler. Like below:

```
    final ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver() {
           super.setTaskScheduler(MYTASKSCHEDULERHERE);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `new A() { ... }` still is just defining a new class. Thus, you cannot simply put any statement between the curly brackets, only field, method and nested type declarations may go there, but constructors are *not* allowed. You may add an instance initializer instead:

```
A extendedClass = new A() {
  {
    x = 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to use nested or anonymous inner class? 
We can do overriding and access the overrided variable as below.

```
public class SomeClass extends A{
    int val;
    void someMethod(int val) {
        super.x = val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
        System.out.println(sc.x);  // output=10
        sc.someMethod(20);
        System.out.println(sc.x);  // output=20
    }

}
class A {
    protected int x = 10; // no public getter, setter
}
```